# Creating a PKCS#12 file where public key doesn't match the private key

Tags: pki

For testing purpose, I want to create a PKCS#12 file in which the private key doesn't match the certificate. Is there any tool which will help me do this?

If I use `openssl pkcs12 -export` command line to create the `p12` file using a cert and a private key which are mismatched, then `openssl` gives me an error

```
No certificate matches private key
```

Is there an alternate tool/way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question, but I wonder what the test case would be.

Comment: @owlstead - test case would be to make sure that ownership of corresponding private key is verified.

Comment: The Java JDK keytool has -storetype pkcs12 support and import/export/delete for certificates, but I will have to try the use case...in the weekend. Maybe try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/). Import your `keystore.p12` store, using the correct password of course or it will (silently) fail. Delete the certificate entry, and import a new "trusted" certificate entry.

Now it could be that some PKCS#12 defined attributes are different (e.g. friendlyName, which is visible as `alias` in portecle. Normally the key and certificate are linked through the modulus value however, so this should not make a difference for anybody trying to use the private key and certificate. It's probably best to copy the `alias` of the certificate just to be sure.

Portecle is written to use the Java `KeyStore` class, which supports PKCS#12 out of the box. The Java `keytool` utility uses the same class, but it seems to automatically delete certificates and keys together so it is not much use here.

Comment: `Import your keystore.p12 store` - I don't have any store. I have a certificate+privatekey file in pkcs#12 format. Is portacle still relevant? Or do I have to first take my p12 file and put it into a java store & then do the portacle operations?

Comment: For Java, on which portecle is build, the P12 file *is* the store. Java KeyStore supports multiple types of store, the native JKS (Java Key Store) but also PKCS#12 out of the box. Note that it *does* expect a DER/binary encoded key store (it does not understand OpenSSL PEM formatted/text format).

Comment: And, did you try my solution?

Comment: How do I delete the certificate entry? When I import my p12 file - I see 1 entry in the main window. When I right click & chose delete - I think it deletes the private key and not the certificate from the p12 file.

Comment: Strange, I certainly saw two entries. I'll investigate... It probably depends on the "friendly name" within PKCS#12

Comment: I am not sure if I have any friendly name. I create the keys and cert in PEM format using openssl. Then using `openssl pkcs12 -export`, I create a PKCS#12 file combining the keys and the cert. However, since PKCS#12 is a standard - I don't think it should should matter how the file is create.